# How to pass constant value in stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have the following statement inside a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO @tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone
                  (ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID,
                   ManagementZoneID,
                   VegetationZoneID)
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/NewDataSet/tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone', 2)
   WITH (ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID INT,
         ManagementZoneID INT,
         VegetationZoneID INT) XMLDATA
   WHERE VegetationZoneID = @VegetationZoneIDInXML
```

Sometime "managementZone id" becomes null, I want to replace if it is null then I want pass the constant value "0". Is there a way to do ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about "passing a constant value", but you can always set a default:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetSalesYTD
@SalesPerson nvarchar(50) = 'Andersson'  -- default value
AS
```

So:

```
@ManagementZoneID INT = 0
```

Comment: Can't do it in my store proc, i have condition with and with out management id inside the store proc, so i might have value some time

Comment: Ok. Can you use explicit select instead of *? If so you could use ISNULL()

Comment: Thanks Mackan, i handled from front end rather than back end to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use a coalesce in the select statement

```
INSERT INTO @tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone
                  ( ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID ,
                    ManagementZoneID        ,
                    VegetationZoneID        
                    )
    SELECT 
          ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID ,
          COALESCE(ManagementZoneID,0)        ,
          VegetationZoneID 
    FROM OPENXML (@hDoc, '/NewDataSet/tblThreatenedSpeciesSubzone', 2)
    WITH            (   ThreatenedSpeciesZoneID INT         ,
                    ManagementZoneID            INT         ,
                    VegetationZoneID            INT             ) XMLDATA
    WHERE VegetationZoneID = @VegetationZoneIDInXML
```